# How to set a different controller for each Angular UI Router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create an Angular UI Router state that specifies a controller for each state. For example I teach english, design, math and a few other courses that I want to display a template based on the subject. I have the proper template loading correctly but my exam controller is getting a little large. I want to separate some of the logic for each subject but not exactly sure on what the best/standard way to achieve that is. I could be over thinking this. Below is what I have so far if anyone has some time to take a look and provide some guidance that would be great.

```
.state('exam', {
url: '/exam',
abstract: true,
views: {
  '':{
    templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam.html',
    controller: 'ExamController',
    controllerAs: 'examController',
  },
  'exam-pagination@exam':{
    templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-pagination.html'
  },
 }
})

.state('exam.subject', {
 url: '/:subject',
 // here I would like to set a controller and controller as
 // based on the subject
 views: {
  'exam-detail@exam' : {
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
      return 'app/state-exam/exam-' + $stateParams.subject + '.html';
    }
  }
 }
});
```

If I did something along these lines is it considered bad practice or flat out wrong?

```
.state('exam', {
url: '/exam',
abstract: true,
views: {
  '':{
    templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam.html',
    controller: 'ExamController',
    controllerAs: 'examController',
  },
  'exam-pagination@exam':{
    templateUrl: 'app/state-exam/exam-pagination.html'
  },
  controller: function($stateParams){
     switch ($stateParams.subject) {
            case 'math':
              return 'ExamMathController'
              break;
             case 'english':
              return 'ExamEnglishController'
              break;
          }
     }
 }
})

.state('exam.subject', {
 url: '/:subject',
 views: {
  'exam-detail@exam' : {
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
      return 'app/state-exam/exam-' + $stateParams.subject + '.html';
    }
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can look the params and do the task as needed.

```
.state('exam.subject', {
 url: '/:subject',
controller:'subjectCtrl',
 // here I would like to set a controller and controller as
 // based on the subject
 views: {
  'exam-detail@exam' : {
    templateUrl: function($stateParams){
      return 'app/state-exam/exam-' + $stateParams.subject + '.html';
    }
  }
 }
});
```

and in controller

```
 .controller('subjectCtrl',['$scope','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$state,$stateParams){
  switch($stateParams.subject){
   case 'English':
  //Task for english subject
break;

case 'Nepali':
//Task for nepali subject
break;
}

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Samundra KC, but wouldn't it be better to have a controller/controller as for each subject? math controller, english controller etc... Just not entirely sure how to go about that.

Comment: you can do it in normal ways like foreach subject each controller